# Grails - Determine if an artefact class is in a given subdirectory of grails-app

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm implementing an [ArtefactHandler](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ArtefactHandler.html) and I want to be able to create artefacts from `Script`s (to support a legacy format). I don't want to make all Scripts into artefacts, but just those in a particular subdirectory of grails-app, say `grails-app/foo/`.

I'm stuck at trying to figure out the path of the artefact from my `ArtefactHandler`'s `isArtefactClass` method. Is there a way to get the path to the original source of the class, or otherwise determine if it's contained in `grails-app/foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails doesn't actually care where on the filesystem your classes are. That's just smoke and mirrors. As such, there is currently no support for location based artefacts, but there is a ticket for it: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2174

In the meantime, the simplest solution is to force your scripts to have a certain naming convention or possibly introduce some kind of marker annotation. I am unsure how to introspect script classes though looking for annotations.

Comment: This is the official answer, I have a hack below.

Answer (score 0):

Luke has the official answer above, but here is the hack I came up with:

```
if (Script.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
    && ((DefaultGrailsApplication) ApplicationHolder.getApplication()).
        getResourceLoader().loadGroovySource(clazz.getName()).
        getPath().contains("grails-app/foo")) {
    return true;
}
```

Which probably has many problems. Firstly it relies on DefaultGrailsApplication being the implementation of GrailsApplication, so we're violating encapsulation. Secondly, it looks like `loadGroovySource` returns null for the built in artefacts (like taglibs) so this may not work on things like plugins and anything distributed in binary form.

EDIT: Looks like it wont even work in production. Back to the drawing board...